# Is there a way ask the user for their name and their favourite colour

Tags: c#

```
I tried Console.WriteLine(“Name:”)
```

Then String name =      Console.ReadLine();
Also Console.WriteLine(“Hair colour”);
String hair colour =
Still doesn’t work for some reason don’t know why but I need help on this it’s for a project

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve] that shows what you've done so far, explain the input you're providing, and what isn't working with more specific details. ."doesn’t work" could mean any number of things. Be specific.

Comment: `String hair colour =` isn't going to work, because `hair colour` is 2 separate words and, therefore, is a syntax error. You need to combine them into 1 word using your preferred notation (e.g., snake case: `hair_colour`, camel case: `hairColour`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get some basic user input, you need to add more variables with readline.

An example would be as follows:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, What's your name?");
    var nameInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Thanks, " + nameInput + " What's your hair colour?");
    var hairColour =  Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Thank you, " + hairColour + " is a nice colour.");
```

Giving a response as well would help the user know there is more input needed from them.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, This is the correct basic way to do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");
var name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Entered Name: " + name);
```